# How to reference function property within an inner scope

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible do this kind of assignment in Kotlin somehow?

```
data class MyData(var v: Int?)

fun myFunction(v: Int) {
    val myData = MyData(null).apply { 
        v = @myFunction.v   //does not work
    }

}
```

PS: the example is unreal is just for the purpose of demonstrating the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.v = v` instead of `v = @myFunction.v`